# Perform hash function in Smarty Template Engine

Tags: php, templates, hash, smarty, sha256

in a smarty template I would like to encrypt a variable using sha256.

with PHP I use

```
hash('sha256', $var);
```

In a smarty template I can use

```
{$var|md5}
```

and it's working but I don't know how to use sha256...

Comment: You can define your own functions. Read this https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins.modifiers.tpl

Comment: _Big Point_ Encryption is not hashing. A hash is not reversable, an encryption can be reversed

Comment: I am tempted to suggest you Hash the variable in the code that calls the smarty

Comment: Here is another simpler way to do it https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.register.plugin.tpl see example Example 14.40 and Example 14.41

Answer (score 0):

To the prestashop (**1.7.5.5**) developer who will pass by this is what I did :

I modified this file in **prestashop/classes/controller/FrontController.php**

I created a variable :

```
$hashEmail = hash('sha256',$this->context->customer->email);
```

Then in the variable :

```
$templateVars
```

I assigned a variable :

```
'hashEmail'=>$hashEmail,
```

And finally in the frontend I displayed my variable :

```
{$hashEmail}
```